# KineticJS memory leak when a stage is created many times

Tags: kineticjs

I use kinetic js 4.5.4.

In my web page I have a button. When a user clicks this button new partial view is applied on the page – in this partial view I create new stage element. When I click many times this button I observe that memory allocation grows very fast. After about 20 clicks allocated memory is about 7GB and the stage becomes black. I have to use F5 to refresh whole page then I also see the memory goes down a lot of – about to 3.5GB.
I was using kinetic API for stage element destroy() and destroyChildren() but it did not help.

Any idea how I can solve this issue?

When I stopped creating in every new partial view a new stage and instead of this reuse the first created stage then I do not observer this problem. So based on this I think something is not right we creating/deleting the stage.

Comment: Why do you need to recreate stage again? create once and leave it there... just redraw what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use kinetic Layers instead of creating a bunch of Stages for your partial views.